# 'XModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: module, npm-install, ng-modules

Most modules in my project in module.ts file say they don't belong to NgModule class. for example; I am getting an error like "'RouterModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class" of RouterModule. This error is giving in all modules. In the error detail, for example; For RouterModule "This likely means that the library (@angular/router) which declares RouterModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy." It shows error like. What is the reason ? Please help me. Thanks.

I tried npm install --force. I tried npm audit fix --force. I tried npm clean cache clean --force and then npm install --force. I tried these methods but could not reach any result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.